# Can I execute nested or chained commands in UNIX shell?

Tags: linux, command-line, ubuntu, nested, solaris

Can I execute command within another command in UNIX shells?

If impossible, can I use the output of the previous command as the input of next command, as in:

`command x` then `command y`,

where in `command y` I want use the output of `command x`?

Comment: @Mohammad: I removed the svn tag since this has nothing to do with svn, it is a general command piping question.

Comment: I think you need to describe the bigger problem that you're having. What *exactly* are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: 1. i want find all repository .... 
2. i want find entire directory for all repository ....
note : the result of execute step one more than 500 repositoy so i need method to execute step two by easy method,,,,

Comment: i execute the following command :-find / -type f -name fs-type -exec svnlook tree {} \; |egrep "/$" ... the result is svnlook: Can't open file '/var/lib/svn/repos/b1me/products/payone/generic/code/core/db/fs-type/format': Not a directory
svnlook: Can't open file '/var/lib/svn/repos/b1me/products/payone/generic/code/fees/db/fs-type/format': Not a directory ..... maybe we must make find command give us path without "db/fs-type/format" but how i can do this ???

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What exactly are you trying to do? It's not clear from the commands you are executing. Perhaps if you describe what you're looking for we can point you in the right direction. If you want to execute a command over a range of file (or directory) names returned by the "find" command, Colin is correct, you need to look at the "-exec" option of "find". If you're looking to execute a command over a bunch of arguments listed in a file or coming from stdin, you need to check out the "xargs" commands. If you want to put the output of a single command on to the command line of another command, then using "$(command)" (or 'command' [replace the ' with a backquote]) will do the job. There's a lot of ways to do this, but without knowing what it is you're trying it's hard to be more helpful.

Answer (score 22):

You can use the backquotes for this.

For example this will cat the file.txt

> cat `echo file.txt`

And this will print the date

> echo the date is `date`

The code between back-quotes will be executed and be replaced by its result.

Comment: please you can give me example in more detail

Comment: but please in the following case what is the solution : i execute "find / -type f -name fs-type -print " this commad found all repository ... now i need to find all directory of repository by this command "svnlook tree /var/lib/lib.org.15-01-2008/svn/repos/pstest | egrep "/$

Comment: Then you need to look at the `-exec` option of find

Comment: is it possible to nest backquotes? I'm trying to use the result of this expression in a command: realpath --relative-to=`pwd` `git top pwd` (where git top is an alias that executes at the top of the repository. the idea is to put that in a find command, which will give me relative paths to the results, for use in a selecta fuzzy selection vim binding.

Comment: googlefoo evidently failed me: here it is http://www.linuxmisc.com/12-unix-shell/d9c594a376ffed37.htm - $ FOO=` echo \\` echo hello \\` ` - i.e. escape the inner ones

Answer (score 15):

You can do something like;

```
x=$(grep $(dirname "$path") file)
```

here `dirname "$path"` will run first and its result will be substituted and then grep will run, searching for the result of `dirname` in the `file`

Comment: but please in the following case what is the solution : i execute "find / -type f -name fs-type -print " this commad found all repository ... now i need to find all directory of repository by this command "svnlook tree /var/lib/lib.org.15-01-2008/svn/repos/pstest | egrep "/$ ..... how i can solve it

Comment: @Mohammed: Add that to your main question.

Comment: i want to find all my repository and then find its entire content

Answer (score -1):

Here is an example where I have used nested system commands.
I had run "ls -ltr" on top of find command. And it executes
it serially on the find output.

ls -ltr $(find . -name "srvm.jar")

Comment: Are you aware of the `-ls` at the end of a `find`? Like here: `find . -name "srvm.jar" -ls`.